# How to get signature of method that is patched in current context?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

In my test I have operation `C.foo()` patched:

```
@patch('C.foo')
def test_bar(self,foo_mock):
    ...
```

I'd like to access original `C.foo()` signature from test_bar's scope (`inspect.signature(<???>)`) How to achieve it?

Comment: 1. Why do you want to access the signature? 2. If you want to access the signature, why are you mocking it?

Comment: Use `with` to patch and access it before.

Comment: Yes: I used with but it would be nice to keep @path decorators instead.

Comment: I want to do this in order to take parameter list and perform some checks on call objects.